# Multiple LIKE in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, search, select, sql-like

I'm trying to create a search function.

If the search input field is "foo bar", I split it into two keywords then do this query:

```
SELECT p.* FROM p_extra_fields as x INNER JOIN products as p ON x.product = p.id
  WHERE x.type = "1"
  AND
  (
     (x.key = "model" AND x.value LIKE "%foo%")
  OR (x.key = "model" AND x.value LIKE "%bar%")
  OR (x.key = "color" AND x.value LIKE "%foo%")
  OR (x.key = "color" AND x.value LIKE "%bar%")
  OR (x.key = "make" AND x.value LIKE "%foo%")
  OR (x.key = "make" AND x.value LIKE "%bar%")
  )      

GROUP BY x.product LIMIT 0, 50
```

The number of keywords may be higher so I might need more "likes". Also the number of "key" can increase :)

Is there any way I could simplify this query? Can I do something like `LIKE("%foo%", "%bar%")` ?

Comment: After a lot of reading I was able to do what you need without installing REGEXP imp or FTS3 and FTS4 extensions, check my solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have [**SQLite FTS3 and FTS4 Extensions**](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) enabled then you can take advantage of Full Text Search (FTS) capabilities. You will need to recreate the `p_extra_fields` table as a [`VIRTUAL`](http://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html) table. Then you can insert `OR` between your search terms and use the `MATCH` operator...

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM p_extra_fields x
JOIN products p ON p.id = x.product
WHERE x.key IN ('model', 'color', 'make')
AND x.type = '1'
AND x.value MATCH 'foo OR bar'
GROUP BY x.product LIMIT 0, 50;
```

Good info [**here**](http://www.phparch.com/2011/11/full-text-search-with-sqlite/) also.
Click [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/8d4e9/1) to see it in action at SQL Fiddle.

Comment: so i have to make a virtual table that's a copy of my `p_extra_fields` table?

Comment: Nice, after some research was able to do it without using ```regex``` and ```match```, check my solution :)

Comment: Important note:  LIKE("%foo%") searches for words that CONTAIN 'foo';  MATCH 'foo' searches for words that ARE EQUAL to 'foo'. As far as I know, with FTS you cannot search for words that contain another word

Answer (score 3):

I think this `where` clause is simpler:

```
  WHERE x.type = "1" and
        x.key in ('model', 'color', 'make') and
        (x.value like '%foo%' or x.value like '%bar%')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same requirement and I was looking for a mechanism that would a match like `REGEXP "A|B|C"` which means match either `A`, `B`, `C`.

So finally this is the solution I came up with:

```
WITH words(str, strSubString, hasComma) AS (
  VALUES ('', "foo,bar", 1)
  UNION ALL SELECT
              SUBSTR(strSubString, 0,
                     CASE WHEN INSTR(strSubString, ',')
                       THEN INSTR(strSubString, ',')
                     ELSE LENGTH(strSubString) + 1 END),
              LTRIM(SUBSTR(strSubString, INSTR(strSubString, ',')), ','),
    INSTR(strSubString, ',')
      FROM ssgPaths
      WHERE hasComma
  )

SELECT p.* FROM p_extra_fields as x INNER JOIN products as p ON x.product = p.id
JOIN words AS w ON x.value LIKE '%' || w.str || '%' AND w.str != ''
WHERE x.type = "1" and x.key in ('model', 'color', 'make');
```

The matching criteria is equivalent to @Gordon's answer:

```
WHERE x.type = "1" and
        x.key in ('model', 'color', 'make') and
        (x.value like '%foo%' or x.value like '%bar%')
```

But this gives you the flexibility of matching the values dynamically depending on your query parameter ( you can extract out `"foo,bar"` to be a parameter).

E.g without changing your query you can pass `"foo,bar,boo"` and till match similar to regex match: `"foo|bar|boo"`